# Why create heap when creating a linked list when we can simply do this?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

I'm studying linked lists from [this lesson.](http://geeksquiz.com/linked-list-set-1-introduction/)

The writer (and all other coders on every single tutorial) goes through creating node type pointer variables, then allocates memory to them using typecasting and malloc. It seems kinda unnecessary to me (Offourse I know I'm missing something), why can't we implement the same using this?

```
struct node 
{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
};

int main()
{
  struct node head;
  struct node second;
  struct node third;

  head.data = 1;
  head.next = &second;

  second.data = 2;
  second.next = &third;

  third.data = 3;
  third.next = NULL;

  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

I've created nodes and the next pointers points towards the addresses of the next nodes...

Comment: Now imagine that you've got to create a million nodes :)

Comment: you can, and by passing callbacks around, and always digging deeper onto the stack, you are effectively turning your stack into a heap, except you also put a return address overhead. Basically, as soon as you return from your function, your list is invalidated, but if you call another function with your current linked list, you are not returning. the difficult part is that you will run out of memory because you can't free any nodes because the unused nodes will still be on the stack. For simple lists like storing steps of factorial, its ok, but not for those that need to free nodes.

Comment: basically, what you are doing is allocating on the stack, except instead of smart allocation like malloc(that can free any node), you are using an allocator that can only release topmost element(s)(unless you want to manually defragment the stack...)

Comment: actually it might be still dangerous since compilers tend to optimize tail recursion, invalidating the links.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's say you create a variable of type `node` called `my_node`:

`struct node my_node;`

You can access its members as `my_node.data` and `my_node.next` because it is not a pointer. Your code, however, will only be able to create 3 nodes. Let's say you have a loop that asks the user for a number and stores that number in the linked list, stopping only when the user types in 0. You don't know when the user will type in 0, so you have to have a way of creating variables while the program is running. "Creating a variable" at runtime is called *dynamic memory allocation* and is done by calling `malloc`, which always returns a pointer. Don't forget to free the dynamically allocated data after it is no longer needed, to do so call the `free` function with the pointer returned by `malloc`. The tutorial you mentioned is just explaining the fundamental concepts of linked lists, in an actual program you're not going to limit yourself to a fixed number of nodes but will instead make the linked list resizable depending on information you only have at runtime (unless a fixed-sized linked list is all you need).

**Edit:**

"Creating a variable at runtime" was just a highly simplified way of explaining the need for pointers. When you call `malloc`, it allocates memory on the heap and gives you an address, which you must store in a pointer.

```
int var = 5;
int * ptr = &var;
```

In this case, `ptr` is a variable (it was declared in all its glory) that holds the address of another variable, and so it is called a pointer. Now consider an excerpt from the tutorial you mentioned:

```
struct node* head = NULL;
head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

In this case, the variable `head` will point to data allocated on the heap at runtime.

If you keep allocating nodes on the heap and assigning the returned address to the `next` member of the last node in the linked list, you will be able to iterate over the linked list simply by writing `pointer_to_node = pointer_to_node->next`. Example:

```
struct node * my_node = head; // my_node points to the first node in the linked list
while (true)
{
    printf("%d\n", my_node->data); // print the data of the node we're iterating over
    my_node = my_node->next; // advance the my_node pointer to the next node
    if (my_node->next == NULL) // let's assume that the 'next' member of the last node is always set to NULL
    {
        printf("%d\n", my_node->data);
        break;
    }
}
```

You can, of course, insert an element into any position of the linked list, not just at the end as I mentioned above. Note though that the only node you ever have a name for is `head`, all the others are accessed through pointers because you can't possibly name all nodes your program will ever have a hold of.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more how malloc can "create a variable at runtime"? I mean a variable has to be first declared like int a; I thought it was used for just allocating memory from the heap

Answer (score 4):

Of course you can do like that. but how far ? how many nodes are you going to create ? We use linkedlists when we don't know how many entries we need when we create the list. So how can you create nodes ? How much ?
That's why we use `malloc()` (or `new` nodes).

Comment: I suspect that whatever you are trying to say is correct, but I don't understand your use of the word "struct". You seem to be using it as a verb.

Comment: Please mention `new` rather than `malloc()` or at least both, as long the OP doesn't really clarifies which language actually was asked for.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the OP linked to a lesson which uses `malloc` in its examples.

Comment: I meant "How many structures are going to make ? You don't know right ? Hence using this method is not a good practice

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ OP gave a link to a C example. Hence I used of malloc. But yeah. I agree. Had to use both the words.....

Comment: @ThisaruGuruge As per my understanding, malloc is just for allocating memory from heap. What does it have to do number of entries we want to create?

Comment: ..because the number of entries may well not be known at compile-time.

Comment: @MartinJames and how does malloc solves that problem? We could use scanf to get the number of entries from the user and design the program accordingly. But I cannot fathom how malloc can help us in that respect...

Answer (score 4):

When you declare 'struct node xyz;' in a function, it exists only so long as that function exists.  If you add it to a linked list and then exit the function, that object no longer exists, but the linked list still has a reference to it.  On the other hand, if you allocate it from the heap and add it to the linked list, it will still exist until it is removed from the linked list and deleted.

This mechanism allows an arbitrary number of nodes to be created at various times throughout your program and inserted into the linked list.  The method you show above only allows a fixed number of specific items to be placed in the list for a short duration.  You can do that, but it serves little purpose, since you could have just accessed the items directly outside the list.

Comment: Good explanation. Thx! But can you give me a few real world examples when the programmer might want to create a linked list that "still exists until it is removed from the linked list and deleted"?

Comment: Easy - any GUI component that is raised by an event-handler fired from a message-loop.  When the event-handler gets back to the GetMessage() call, (or whatever), all automatic-storage objects have gone, but the window components created must remain.

Comment: A linked list is a container, and you will always want to allocate independent objects, throw them into the list, and relinquish ownership and responsibility for the object and the memory is consumes.  Say your list is a dictionary, sorted alphabetically.  You read the words in from a file.  Each one gets read into a single temporary buffer.  Then a node is allocated to hold it, the word is copied into the node, and it is placed in the linked list.

Answer (score 3):

But what if you had a file containing an unknown number of entries, and you needed to iterate over them, adding each one to the linked list? Think about how you might do that without `malloc`.

You would have a loop, and in each iteration you need to create a completely new "instance" of a node, different to all the other nodes. If you just had a bunch of locals, each loop iteration they would still be the same locals.

Answer (score 2):

Your code and approach is correct as long as you know the number of nodes that you need in advance. In many cases, though, the number of nodes depends on user input and is not known in advance.

You definitely have to decide between C and C++, because typecasting and malloc belong in C only. Your C++ linked list code won't be doing typecasting nor using `malloc` precisely because it's not C code, but C++ code.

Comment: The language is C not C++, my bad.

Comment: But if I understand correctly, malloc is just for allocating memory from heap. What does it have to do with user input? The writer of the article doesn't ask for user input either...

Comment: @nos ummm...okay. Since I'm a beginner I may not be the best person to judge the quality of the article. Can you please suggest a good one? Or else, can you just tell me the text/website/book/video that you read when learning linked lists and the related concepts?

Comment: +1: exactly.  In a GUI system, the compiler does not know in advance how many windows might get opened and how many visual components may need to be preserved across calls.

Answer (score 0):

Say you are writing an application such as a text editor.  The writer of the application has no idea how big a file a user in the future may want to edit.

Making the editor always use a large amount of memory is not helpful in multi-tasking environments, especially one with a large number of users.

With **malloc()** an editing application can take additional amounts of memory from the heap as required, with different processes using different amounts of memory, without large amounts of memory being wasted.

Answer (score 0):

You can, and you can exploit this technique to create cute code like this, to use the stack as a malloc in a way:

The code below should be safe enough assuming there are no tail optimizations enabled.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node_t {
    struct node_t *next;
    int cur;
    int n;
} node_t;

void factorial(node_t *state, void (*then)(node_t *))
{
    node_t tmp;

    if (state->n <= 1) {
        then(state);
    } else {
        tmp.next = state;
        tmp.cur = state->n * state->cur;
        tmp.n = state->n - 1;
        printf("down: %x %d %d.\n", tmp);
        factorial(&tmp, then);
        printf("up: %x %d %d.\n", tmp);
    }
}

void andThen(node_t *result)
{    
    while (result != (node_t *)0) {
        printf("printing: %x %d %d.\n", *result);
        result = result->next;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    node_t initial_state;
    node_t *result_state;
    initial_state.next = (node_t *)0;
    initial_state.n = 6; // factorial of
    initial_state.cur = 1; // identity for factorial

    factorial(&initial_state, andThen);
}
```

result:

```
$ ./fact
down: 28ff34 6 5.
down: 28ff04 30 4.
down: 28fed4 120 3.
down: 28fea4 360 2.
down: 28fe74 720 1.
printing: 28fe74 720 1.
printing: 28fea4 360 2.
printing: 28fed4 120 3.
printing: 28ff04 30 4.
printing: 28ff34 6 5.
printing: 0 1 6.
up: 28fe74 720 1.
up: 28fea4 360 2.
up: 28fed4 120 3.
up: 28ff04 30 4.
up: 28ff34 6 5.
```

factorial works differently than usual because we can't return the result to caller because the caller will invalidate it with any single stack operation. a single function call will destroy the result, so instead, we must pass it to another function that will have its own frame on top of the current result, which will not invalidate the arbitrary number of stack frames it's sitting on top of that hold our nodes.

I imagine there are many ways for this to break other than tail call optimizations, but it's really elegant when it doesn't, because the links are guaranteed to be fairly cache local, since they are fairly close to each other, and there is no malloc/free needed for arbitrary sized consecutive allocations, since everything is cleaned as soon as returns happen.

Answer (score 0):

Lets think you are making an Application like CHROME web browser, then you wanna create link between tabs created by user at run time which can only possible if you use Dynamic Memory Allocation.
That's why we use `new`, `malloc()` etc to apply dynamic memory allocation.
☺:).